# ROS2/pendulum demo (and rttest/example_loop) get killed if 8GB free RAM is not satisfied

Tags: ros, ros2, real-time, realtime

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi !

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 with a real-time patched kernel (4.14.93-rt53). I have tested my system with cyclic tests and am happy about the realtime performance.

I have built and installed Ros2 (Crystal Clemmys) according to this manual: https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Installation/Linux-Development-Setup/. The talker and listener examples work fine.

When I try to run the pendulum demo (https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Tutorials/Real-Time-Programming/#run-the-tests) I get an unexpected output:

```
$ RMW_IMPLEMENTATION=rmw_connext_cpp pendulum_demo
RTI Data Distribution Service Non-commercial license is for academic, research, evaluation and personal use only. USE FOR COMMERCIAL PURPOSES IS PROHIBITED. See RTI_LICENSE.TXT for terms. Download free tools at rti.com/ncl. License issued to Non-Commercial User license@rti.com For non-production use only.
Expires on 00-jan-00 See www.rti.com for more information.
RTI Data Distribution Service Non-commercial license is for academic, research, evaluation and personal use only. USE FOR COMMERCIAL PURPOSES IS PROHIBITED. See RTI_LICENSE.TXT for terms. Download free tools at rti.com/ncl. License issued to Non-Commercial User license@rti.com For non-production use only.
Expires on 00-jan-00 See www.rti.com for more information.
Couldn't set scheduling priority and policy: Operation not permitted
Killed
```

I could get rid of the line:

```
 Couldn't set scheduling priority and policy: Operation not permitted
```

I have tried to give the rights according to this: https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Tutorials/Real-Time-Programming/#setting-permissions-for-the-scheduler

I can also see (after logon/logoff) that the rights are updated accordingly:

```
$ ulimit -r
98
```

Now the output is without this line, but still gets killed:

```
$ RMW_IMPLEMENTATION=rmw_connext_cpp pendulum_demo
RTI Data Distribution Service Non-commercial license is for academic, research, evaluation and personal use only. USE FOR COMMERCIAL PURPOSES IS PROHIBITED. See RTI_LICENSE.TXT for terms. Download free tools at rti.com/ncl. License issued to Non-Commercial User license@rti.com For non-production use only.
Expires on 00-jan-00 See www.rti.com for more information.
RTI Data Distribution Service Non-commercial license is for academic, research, evaluation and personal use only. USE FOR COMMERCIAL PURPOSES IS PROHIBITED. See RTI_LICENSE.TXT for terms. Download free tools at rti.com/ncl. License issued to Non-Commercial User license@rti.com For non-production use only.
Expires on 00-jan-00 See www.rti.com for more information.
Killed
```

I have found a very similar (unanswered) question and initially posted mine (by mistake) as an answer here:
https://answers.ros.org/question/303072/ros2pendulum-demo-freezes-the-system/?answer=314834#post-id-314834

I would be happy to receive any Input. Since I am inexperienced with Ros, it might very well be some rookie mistake.
Thank you!
Nicolas

**Update: Testing with rttest and debugging with gdb**

According [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/)'s suggestion I have tested `example_loop` from [ros2/realtime_support/rttest](https://github.com/ros2/realtime_support/tree/master/rttest). Unfortunately this program gets Killed as well.

To debug the `example_loop` with `gdb` I have rebuild and started with

```
$ cmake ../ -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug 
$ make

$ gdb ./example_loop
(gdb) r
```

and received the following output:

```
Starting program: /home/<myUserName>/realtime_support/rttest/examples/build/example_loop
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Program terminated with signal SIGKILL, Killed.
The program no longer exists.
(gdb) bt
No stack.
(gdb)
```

to check my user's permission (Thanks a lot for your support, I appreciate any guesse/suggestions!):

```
$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 30272
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) unlimited
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 98
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 30272
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

So far I have only tested it on this machine. I have created the Kernel according to this instruction [Building-Realtime-rt_preempt-kernel-for-ROS-2](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Tutorials/Building-Realtime-rt_preempt-kernel-for-ROS-2/).

I have used the latest stable RT_PREEMT patch (patch-4.14.93-rt53.patch.gz  from http://cdn.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/rt/4.14/, linked by https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/realtime/start).
I have applied this patch to the Kernel source linux-4.14.93.tar.xz, which I have taken from https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/v4.x/ .

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/314846/ros2/pendulum-demo-(and-rttest/example_loop)-get-killed-if-8gb-free-ram-is-not-satisfied./) by [Nicolas Gerig](https://answers.ros.org/users/39882/nicolas-gerig/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2019-02-06

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-02-06**:
Can you test whether `example_loop` from [ros2/realtime_support/rttest](https://github.com/ros2/realtime_support/tree/master/rttest) does work? If that also gets killed, then something is wrong.

You might want to see whether `gdb` can help clear up the mystery in that case.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-02-06**:
Btw: your question title still mentions the privilege issue, but in your latest output I don't see it any more.

**Comment by [Nicolas Gerig](https://answers.ros.org/users/39882/nicolas-gerig/) on 2019-02-07**:
Hi gvdhoorn,
Thank you for your support! I have updated the title and tested the example_loop. Unfortunately, the example loop gets killed as well:

```
./example_loop
Killed
```

Sorry for taking so long to test your suggestion.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-02-07**:
First thing I'd try is run it in `gdb`.

**Comment by [Nicolas Gerig](https://answers.ros.org/users/39882/nicolas-gerig/) on 2019-02-07**:
I am trying to do that now (never used gdb before). I have rebuilt example_loop to add debug info:
$ cmake ../ -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
$ make
Started the debugging by
$ gdb ./example_loop
It prints infor about gbd, then reads the symbols, and stays with (gdb). I dont see any CPU usage.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-02-07**:
Once `gdb` has started, you type `r` (short for `run`) and press enter.

It will probably start outputting all sorts of info. After it gets killed, copy-paste all that into your question (use the `edit` button/link).

If possible, also type `bt` and press enter, after it's killed.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-02-07**:
re: your edit: it could be that your user doesn't have the permission to request the large stacks that `realtime_support` is trying to use. What is the output of `ulimit -a`?

Note: I'm not sure here, just guessing at this point, as your program just getting killed isn't very informative.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-02-07**:
Also: have you tried running the same program on a different machine? How did you create the kernel?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2019-02-07**:
A common readon for "Killed" messages is that you ran out of memory. You should check `dmesg` to see if the OOM killer was activated. It creates a log there.

**Comment by [Nicolas Gerig](https://answers.ros.org/users/39882/nicolas-gerig/) on 2019-02-07**:
Thank you for your hints! I will investigate memory usage (and install the setup on a different machine as well). Unfortunately, I will be out of the lab for the next 10 days - so this thread will be put on hold and I will update as soon as I can continue testing.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-04**:
@Nicolas Gerig: please post your last edit as an answer and then accept your own answer. That will show much more clearly that your question was resolved/answered.

> 8GB of RAM, which is not enough according to the example manuals.

could you also link & quote from the documentation you refer to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Found the issue, my bad.**

Thank you all for your valuable feedback!
I have learnt a lot already while testing the below steps. However, my failure was rather trivial - the PC I have borrowed from our IT did only have 8GB of RAM, which is not enough according to the example tutorial of the [pendulum_demo](https://index.ros.org/doc/ros2/Tutorials/Real-Time-Programming/#run-the-tests)  it requires at least 8GB of free RAM (from the *Run the tests* section):

> Before you run make sure you have at least 8Gb of RAM free. With the memory locking, swap will not work anymore.

I failed to check the PC specs and the requirement in the example manual. However, it is interesting to note that not only the `pendulum_demo`, but also `example_loop` from [ros2/realtime_support/rttest](https://github.com/ros2/realtime_support/tree/master/rttest) required more RAM than was available in the tested PC. By using `htop` in a seperate console I could follow how the memory is filled after either programm start and the programm being killed exactly once the memory is full.

---

Originally posted by [Nicolas Gerig](https://answers.ros.org/users/39882/nicolas-gerig/) with karma: 11 on 2019-03-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0